# Where has Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Tables gone?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

On the GitHub page for https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net it states 
"As of 9.4.0, Tables are not supported by this library."

Does anyone know where this namespace has gone ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that (despite the confusing name) it has been put in with the CosmosDB table package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table

Answer (score 3):

There have been multiple renames and moves of the .NET SDK for Azure Storage tables. The versions go like this, chronologically:

1. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table
2. Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table
3. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table
4. [Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/)

For some time, the SDK became part of the Azure Cosmos DB SDK (instead of Azure Storage SDK), allegedly [to ease the migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/44722/is-azure-table-storage-deprecated-as-of-now.html), but now it has its own package that seems to go in the direction of separation and unification as part of the implementation of the [Track2 architecture of Azure SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68343054/2157640).

There is a [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/MigrationGuide.md) to the new SDK, but it does not cover the first SDK version in the sequence, which is sadly the one this question is about.