# What is Azure track2 SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

In [release notes of Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli?tabs=azure-cli), I see references to "track2 SDK", which I don't understand. When I tried googling, I found [Azure SDK API review process](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/policies_reviewprocess.html), which mentions that only track 2 libraries are reviewed by architecture board, but that does not help in understanding what track 2 is.

Comment: From that same link (2nd one): `By definition, a Track 2 library is one that follows our Track 2 library design guidelines and specific language guidelines. This means that libraries produced solely by a code generator do NOT follow these guidelines; engineers MUST build a layer on top of the generated code in order to produce a library that meets the guidelines.`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @GauravMantri, I read that and probably missed the "by definition" part of the sentence. Still, I was hoping for a more practical explanation that helps understand why a user should care, e.g. which interesting properties do these guidelines give to the libraries, which specific well known libraries are track 2 and which ones are not, what good does it make to include such a piece of info in the release notes of Azure CLI, where did the name track2 come from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track2 corresponds to the major revamp of Azure SDK client libraries. One of the goal for such major revamp is to improve the consistency among different languages SDK via adhering to guidelines outlined in [Azure SDKs Guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/general_design.html)

The majority of Azure SDKs is auto-generated by [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/AutoRest), Track2 generally corresponds to v3+ of each language autorest generator, with generated code being vastly different to previously generated with v2 generators. This will generally require migration, once Track2 SDK updates land, each SDK should provide its own migration guide like [servicebus/migration-guide.md](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/migration-guide.md)

Related: [Track 2 Migration Guidance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/track_2_migration_guidance.md)

Comment: Is this about Track2? https://aka.ms/azsdkvalueprop
Is it about the v11 to v12 shift I noticed in Azure Storage SDK for .NET?

Comment: The v11 to v12 shift is described in the README.md of the v11 repos... https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/README.md

Comment: it sounds like it is